# SQL 2012 - Indexing User table fields Email and Password for performance reasons

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

When doing a standard LOGIN process where you pass an Email and Password, does it make sense to INDEX those 2 fields?

There are No FK on those 2 fields from other tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It makes sense. If the authentification system is based on email + password and if both columns are in the same table then I would create the following index (SQL2005+):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IUN_MyTable_EmailAddress#Password
ON dbo.MyTable(EmailAddress)
INCLUDE (Password);
```

The index has a double usage:

**First**: it will prevent duplicated users = duplicated emails (more or less: see `bogdan@gmail.com` vs. `bog.dan@gmail.com`)

and

**Second**: it helps following queries

```
SELECT ...
FROM dbo.MyTable t
WHERE t.EmailAddress = @pEmailAddress
```

or

```
SELECT ...
FROM dbo.MyTable t
WHERE t.EmailAddress = @pEmailAddress
AND t.Password = @pPassword
-- 'p' prefix = parameter
```

Note: I would use a lower (than 100) fill factor for this index. For example I would start with  fill factor 90 and periodically I would [check to see if there are to many page splits](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/michael_zilberstein/archive/2011/04/25/35175.aspx). Depending on these observations I would decrease/increase more or less this fill factor.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your query.

- Do you have both email in password in your `WHERE` clause? Then go for an index that has both columns.
- Do you search by email and retrieve password. Create an index on email and include password column.

There's rarely a one-size-fits-all solution. You really need to analyse your code and check your circumstances. Indexes are in most cases great but you have to keep in mind that they take some additional disk space and updating them costs time.